# Small doubt in asynchronous counter

Tags: counter, ripple-counter

I was trying to understand the ripple effect in asynchronous counter and I came across this figure:-

[image]

In all the problems solved in my book, they consider the minimum clock period required for proper functioning of counter as the sum of the delays caused due to these flip flops.

If we consider each delay as 5ns in the figure then the answer would be 15ns (minimum clock period time) according to my book.

My doubt is if it is exactly 15ns, then after 15ns, Q0 will toggle and we would get "1". So at the end we can't get 1000 as output as by that time Q0 would have toggled and we would get 1001 skipping 1000.

So I don't understand how clock period of 15ns would solve the problem of rippling.

Can someone please help me understand this concept?

ref:- https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-11/asynchronous-counters/

Comment: add the clock signal to the diagram

Comment: I am not able to understand what will be the time period of the clock signal(thats my doubt). How can I add it? I edited the question with the reference link from where I took the diagram.

Comment: If the ceiling is exactly your height, are you going to bump your head on it?

Comment: @BrianDrummond \*Takes a blunt\* Woaaah maaan. So deep dude. Duuuuude.

Comment: @Zephyr, the first timing diagram on the web page shows the clock rising edge being the clocking signal for the first flip-flop. .... as per diagram on the bottom, the outputs are allowed to update in the receiving circuit when the clock goes low.   therefore the clock has to stay high until the last flip-flop output is valid. .... for your example, the clock high has to be more than 15ns .... draw the clock into the diagram above .... rising when Q0 goes low and falling just after Q3 goes high

Comment: @jsotola But if I exactly draw the negative edge or falling edge along the line when Q3 goes high then QO will toggle at that time and at the end I will get output as "1" and not "0" which will make final output as 1001 and not 1000 according to me.

Comment: Q0 toggles on the rising edge of the clock .... clock goes high, which starts the "chain reaction", and it has to stay high until everything settles, that's all

Comment: Do I miss anything - how Q3 can change state of Q0 if Q3 is not connected within counter circuit to any input?

Comment: Q3 does not change the state of Q0, the clock changes the state of Q0

Comment: @jsotola In the 2nd diagram on webpage, the toggling is during the negative edge and not during positive edge I guess.

Comment: @jsotola Unfortunately I still couldn't understand how can exact 15ns clock period  ensure proper counting .

Comment: @jsotola Yes and even I think the same but Brian says that it is possible and my book says it too :(.

Comment: @jsotola He said that if ceiling is exactly your height then you are not gonna bump your head. It means if clock cycle is exactly 15ns then its not gonna cause problem.

Comment: ok, i re-read it. "**minimum clock period** required for proper functioning" ... meaning that less than 15ns will fail every time Q3 changes ( it is not period though, it is pulse width)  .... 15ns exactly is playing with fate

Comment: @jsotola Actually it's the period :P (minimum clock period required ).

Comment: i was wrong ... the term is "time high" .... period is as i said before, "time high" plus "time low" (it is the complete cycle) ... the question is using incorrect terminology